# How to push into a tag on Git?

Tags: git, tags, branch, clone

This is the first time I'm using tag on Git, so I've a question.

First, I cloned my repository (from the `master` branch) and modified the code.

Then, I want on Gitlab and created a new tag from the GUI: `Repository -> Tags -> New Tag.`
At, this point I've a new tag, `TAG_A`.

Now, I'd like to push my modified code into the `TAG_A`. How can I do it?

Comment: You don't "push code into a tag". A tag *names a commit*. The commit already exists, and once a commit exists and has its assigned hash ID, the contents *in* that commit are frozen for all time. The tag just gives you a human-readable name for that commit hash ID—plus (if it's an *annotated* tag) a tag message and perhaps a GPG signature or whatever, to indicate that you endorse that particular commit.

Comment: So I do a commit giving specifying a tag? How can I do this?

Comment: You create a tag after the commit. Not the other way around.

Comment: why do you want to commit to a tag? I think you're confusing tag with branch. a tag points to a specific "moment" in the project's history. so your next commit comes after the tag you created before

Comment: Git is all about *commits*. You make commits. If they're not right, you make more commits. When you have a commit that you like a whole lot, you tell people to use that commit, by giving out its hash ID. But hash IDs are big and ugly and hard to type in correctly, so you can give out a tag name like `v2.1` instead, which humans can handle. You're still really giving out the commit hash ID.

Answer (score 0):

In order to push to your GitLab repository, it is best to [create a branch](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/web_editor.html#create-a-new-branch-from-a-projects-dashboard) instead of a tag (see [GitLab branch](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/branches/)):

[image: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/img/web_editor_new_branch_dropdown_v14_1.png]

That way, you can create the same branch locally, add commits and push:

```
cd /path/to/local/repository
git fetch
git switch -c myBranch origin/master
# work, add, commit...
git push -u origin myBranch
```